# How does the Samba misconfigured '/etc/passwd' file security bypass vulnerability work?

Tags: linux, penetration-test

I just found this vulnerability on http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/36363/references, which affects several samba server 3.0.xx.

Can anyone explain more about this vulnerability? How this bypass happens if I do not allow anyone to access to shares without password, and possible counter-measures to this issue besides updating to latest samba version? I did not find any further details online.

Comment: A considerable part of su!h security alarms exist only as a theoretical possibility, but maybe somebody knows it better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the following quote explains the vulnerability best:

> A flaw was discovered in the way Samba handled users without a home directory set in the back-end password database (e.g. "/etc/passwd"). If a share for the home directory of such a user was created (e.g. using the automated "[homes]" share), any user able to access that share could see the whole file system, possibly bypassing intended access restrictions.

So it's not authentication that is bypassed here. It's just that the authenticated user will see the entire file system, not just his home share. Note that access will still be subject to file and directory permissions.